# How do I add user to database in django admin without using admin interface?

Tags: django, django-admin

So far I’ve added 3 users using interactive shell but why are they not visible in admin interface?

```
>>>from django.contrib.auth.models import User

>>> User.objects.all()

[<User: usr1>, <User: usr2>, <User: usr3>]
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using `django.contrib.auth.models.User` as your main auth model?

The superuser you're using to access the admin interface should be listed as one of the users in `Users.objects.all()` and it doesn't seem to be in the list, so I guess you're seeing another model.

What do you get when you type this in the shell?

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>>> settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
>>> get_user_model().objects.all()
```

If you get a different user set, then you are overriding the auth model.
More info at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: It's better to use `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model` than coming up with your own solution.

Comment: You are right, I didn't know about this function. Will correct my answer.